# How do I use AWS credentials with Jenkins to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have entered AWS credentials in Jenkins at `/credentials`, however they do not show up in the drop down list for the Post Build steps in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk plugin.

[image]

If I click Validate Credentials, I get this strange error.

[image]

> Failure
>       com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@5c932b96: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@32abba7: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/]
>           at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)

I don't know where it got that IP address. When I search for that IP in the Jenkins directory, I turn up with

```
-bash-4.2$ grep -r 169.254.169.254 *
plugins/ec2/AMI-Scripts/ubuntu-init.py:conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("169.254.169.254")
```

The contents of that file is here: https://pastebin.com/3ShanSSw

---

There are actually 2 different Amazon Elastic Beanstalk plugins.

- [AWSEB Deployment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin), v 0.3.19, Aldrin Leal
- [AWS Beanstalk Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWS+Beanstalk+Publisher+Plugin), v 1.7.4, David Tanner

Neither of them work. Neither will display the credentials in the drop down list. Since updating Jenkins, I am unable to even show "Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk" as a post-build step for the first one (v0.3.19) even though it is the only one installed.

For the 2nd plugin (v1.7.4), I see this screen shot:

[image]

When I fill in what I can, and run it, it gives the error

```
No credentials provided for build!!!
Environment found (environment id='e-yfwqnurxh6', name='appenvironment'). Attempting to update environment to version label 'sprint5-13'
'appenvironment': Attempt 0/5
'appenvironment': Problem:
com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.AWSElasticBeanstalkException: No Application Version named 'sprint5-13' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: af9eae4f-ad56-426e-8fe4-4ae75548f3b1)
```

---

I tried to add an S3 sub-task to the Elastic Beanstalk deployment, but it failed with an exception.

> No credentials provided for build!!!
>   Root File Object is a file. We assume its a zip file, which is okay.
>   Uploading file awseb-4831053374102655095.zip as s3://appname-sprint5-15.zip
>   ERROR: Build step failed with exception
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 7C4734153DB2BC36; S3 Extended Request ID: x7B5HflSeiIw++NGosos08zO5DxP3WIzrUPkZOjjbBv856os69QRBVgic62nW3GpMtBj1IxW7tc=), S3 Extended Request ID: x7B5HflSeiIw++NGosos08zO5DxP3WIzrUPkZOjjbBv856os69QRBVgic62nW3GpMtBj1IxW7tc=

Comment: "I don't know where it got that IP address." that'd b the EC2 metadata service, and it's a really excellent way to expose credentials to apps running on AWS . If your jenkins instance is on AWS, look it up, it's a game changer.    The default credentials provider chain checks several locations, generally checking the metadata service after hard coded creds, environment variables, default profile in ~/.aws, etc.  Though it's java, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html, though java, does a good job explaining the steps it takes.

Comment: But the IP is dead. The site can't be reached. `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

Comment: are you on ec2?

Comment: Well Jenkins is on EC2. I'm on my laptop. If I do `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` from the Jenkins server, then I get a 404 error and minimal 404 HTML page.

Comment: I'd imagine, then, you haven't given the EC2 instance hosting your jenkins server an instance profile and/or role.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is hopelessly out of date and unmaintained. I added the Post Build Task plugin, [installed `eb` tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html) as `jenkins` user, ran `eb init` in the job directory, edited `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` to add the lines

```
deploy:
  artifact: target/AppName-Sprint5-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip
```

Then entered in the shell command to deploy the build.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.local/bin/eb deploy -l sprint5-${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Eleastic beanstalk plugin right place to configure AWS key is Jenkins Master configure

```
  http://{jenkinsURL}/configure
```